# Windows universal Right to Left support

Tags: c#, uwp

Необходимо сделать поддержку арабского варианта раскладок (как текста, так и layout-ов). Насколько я понимаю, при установке в родительском Grid-e свойства FlowDirection="RightToLeft" во всех дочерних айтемах все унаследуется. 
Вопрос - а есть ли какие-то стандартные настройки, при переназначении которых перевернется вся аппликуха вообще?

Comment: А если просто установить FlowDirection топ-элементу (страница или окно, что там в UWP?)

Comment: Да, про это я и говорю, что можно. Но в аппликухе, например, 100 фреймов, каждому надо такое устанавливать, или есть способ "задать сразу всем" ?

Comment: А, понял вопрос. Где-то у меня был такой фокус, попробую найти дома.

Comment: Так а если сделать свой контрол, который будет наследован от контрола в котором по умолчанию уже сразу будет установлено свойство RightToLeft

Comment: Влад, ага, спасибо!
Алексей, об этом как раз и говорили выше, что с наследованием все ок, но это наследование прийдется применять для всех, скажем, родительских гридов. А вопрос в том, можно ли решить это как то с помощью настроек или другого одноразового решения, не меняя весь код.